# find start and end dates over a non-contiguous range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to find the start and end dates of range defined as: start date is the first date and the end date is the first date where the subsequent date is two months or more after the end date. There can be multiple possible ranges

I have a table structure like:

```
ID        int  identity(1,1),
fk_ID     char(9),
dateField datetime
```

The data looks like:

```
1     a     2012-01-01
2     a     2012-01-05
3     a     2012-01-12
4     b     2012-02-01
5     a     2012-04-01
6     b     2012-05-01
7     a     2012-05-30
```

The expected output would look like:

```
fk_id    startdate    enddate
a        2012-01-01   2012-01-12
a        2012-04-01   2012-05-30
b        2012-02-01   2012-02-01
b        2012-05-01   null
```

EDIT:
By doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    autonum     int     identity(1,1),
    id          char(9),
    sd          datetime
)

insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-05')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-12')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-03-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-04-03')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-06-06')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-02-12')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-02-15')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-03-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-04-03')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-06-01')

select t1.id, null as previousend, min(t1.sd) as nextstart
from #temp t1
group by t1.id
union
select t1.id, t1.sd as enddate, (select min(t2.sd) from #temp t2 where t1.id=t2.id and    t2.sd>t1.sd) as nextstart
from #temp t1
where (select min(t2.sd) from #temp t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.sd>t1.sd) >= dateadd(month, 2, t1.sd)
union
select t1.id, max(t1.sd), null
from #temp t1
group by t1.id

drop table #temp
```

I can get output like this:

```
id        previousend             nextstart
--------- ----------------------- -----------------------
a         NULL                    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
a         2012-04-03 00:00:00.000 2012-06-06 00:00:00.000
a         2012-06-06 00:00:00.000 NULL
b         NULL                    2012-02-12 00:00:00.000
b         2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Which is very close, but ideally the start and end date of the range would be on the row.

Comment: I think you meant _...and the end date is the first date where the subsequent date is two months or more after the **start** date_, right?

Comment: @alfonso unfortunately the description is accurate, if a little confusing. The data example hopefully clarifies the situation.

Comment: You've shown what is "very close" on your second, different set of sample data. Can you show what you actually want as a result in that case instead of vaguely describing it with another confusing word problem?

Comment: In your first example, you seem to let the enddate be null for b, since there is only one date in the second range for that id. However in the second example, you haven't shown the actual result you want, but from the looks of what you're getting now you don't seem to want null for the end date for that last range for a, which only has only date. This is just getting more and more confusing and very difficult to solve both examples with a single query. Can you please submit a new question with a single, cohesive problem statement and a single set of sample data and desired results please?

Comment: Your sample data should cover all edge cases so that people don't waste their time crafting a solution that works until you throw an extra row in there...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I apologize if the description I provided was not clear. The request I received was to find the start and end dates where the end date for a row was followed by a two or more month gap before the next date. There was no specification for how the most recent dates fit, that is why my expected output was lacking. Again, I apologize if you feel your time was wasted and I do appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Ok, well did you see my updated answer? Do you see how the requirement you've listed is unclear? A good sanity check is to read your question forgetting about any knowledge you have and try to answer it with the information given. And I don't mean write the query, obviously you wouldn't be here if you knew the answer. I just mean try to figure out if you understand the requirement and can determine how ou might try to solve the problem. I the requirements are unclear or conflicting it can very hard to get anywhere (as you can see in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best guess given all the changes to the question. I still find the problem very confusing, splintered and that the desired results for the two cases don't seem to match. With this query:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT a.id, sd = a.sd, ed = b.sd, rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY a.id, a.sd ORDER BY a.sd)
  FROM #temp AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp AS b
  ON a.id = b.id
  AND b.sd >= a.sd
  AND b.sd <= DATEADD(MONTH, 2, a.sd)
),
y AS 
(SELECT id, sd, 
  ed = (SELECT MAX(ed) FROM x AS x2 
    WHERE x.id = x2.id AND x2.sd <= DATEADD(MONTH, 2, x.sd)
  )
FROM x
WHERE rn1 = 1
),
z AS 
(
  SELECT id, sd = MIN(sd), ed
  FROM y GROUP BY id, ed
)
SELECT id, sd, ed /* = CASE 
  WHEN ed > sd OR (sd = ed AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM z AS z2 WHERE z2.id = z.id AND z.sd > z2.sd)) THEN ed END 
*/
FROM z
ORDER BY id, sd;
```

The results for your first set of data:

```
INSERT #temp (id, sd) VALUES
('a','2012-01-01'),
('a','2012-01-05'),
('a','2012-01-12'),
('b','2012-02-01'),
('a','2012-04-01'),
('b','2012-05-01'),
('a','2012-05-30');
```

Is as follows:

```
id  sd          ed
a   2012-01-01  2012-01-12
a   2012-04-01  2012-05-30
b   2012-02-01  2012-02-01
b   2012-05-01  2012-05-01
```

And for the second set:

```
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-05')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-01-12')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-03-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-04-03')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('a', '2012-06-06')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-02-12')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-02-15')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-03-01')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-04-03')
insert into #temp (id, sd) values ('b', '2012-06-01')
```

Is as follows:

```
id  sd          ed
a   2012-01-01  2012-04-03
a   2012-06-06  2012-06-06
b   2012-02-12  2012-06-01
```

If you uncomment the CASE block you'll get NULLs for the end date where the start date and end date are the same. As I suggested multiple times, your question is splintered and your desired results don't seem to match, so I'm not sure what the right answer is.

Comment: This works exactly as I needed. Can you recommend a source on CTEs to help me understand what is happening here? Thanks again

Comment: A CTE is nothing more than a derived table, but the syntax allows you to reference it more than once in the subsequent query. I'd say [here](http://www.learnkey.com/elearning/PDFs/Common%20Table%20Expressions.pdf) and [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) are good starts.

Comment: I was premature with selecting this answer. I added 1 row: ID=7 FK_ID=a dateField='2012-02-01'. Adding the date from another month throws off all of output.

Comment: Well of course, you also seem to have changed the actual question to include previousend and added other variables. Pretty hard to hit a moving target. :-(

Comment: The previous end and next start were the only way that I was able to get the start and end dates for the range.

Answer (score 1):

attempt number two which is on [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec93c/1) and is far from elegant but seems to work apart from the final record not being NULL for the end date:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    id          char(9),
    d          datetime
);

insert into temp (id, d) values ('a', '2012-01-01');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('a', '2012-01-05');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('a', '2012-01-12');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('a', '2012-04-01');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('a', '2012-05-30');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('b', '2012-02-01');
insert into temp (id, d) values ('b', '2012-05-01');


SELECT 
   x.id ,
   min(x.sd) sd ,
   x.ed
FROM
  (SELECT 
      a.id ,
      a.sd ,
      max(a.ed) ed
   FROM
      ( 
      SELECT 
          j.id ,
          j.d sd ,
          q.D ed
       FROM temp j
          JOIN temp q 
             ON 
             j.id = q.id
             AND j.d <= q.d
       GROUP BY j.id ,
           j.d ,
           q.d 
      ) a
   WHERE datediff(m,a.sd,a.ed)<=2
   GROUP BY a.id ,
        a.sd
         )x
GROUP BY x.id ,
         x.ed
ORDER BY x.id ,
         min(x.sd) ,
         x.ed
```

Comment: The sample fiddle first result shows start date Jan 1 2012, end date Sep 1 2012. It should be start date Jan 1 2012, end date Jan 2 2012. Start date Sep 1 2012, end date null.

Comment: YEP  - apologies I had misread the question; I'm not sure how to answer this question and look forward to seeing the final answer

Comment: continued fiddling but the problem is really messing up my Sunday afternoon: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3f67/15

Comment: I've totall reworked the answer with a new fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec93c/2